# ASP.Net Label control's Text property not updating text under button click event

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, user-controls

I have developed a small application in SharePoint. I am using custom application page and load .ascx Control over that page under Page_Load() method. In .ascx Control, I have created a small form with text boxes and a button Control. under this button click event, I want to change the text property of label like: lblConfirmation.Text = "Confirmation is OK"; but it did not change the text. It shows nothing because i set text property empty in label Control.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblConfirmation" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
```

Any Idea, what is wrong ?

Comment: Can you please share your PageLoad event code...?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to check if it's a real postback or a first page load in your Page_Load() method... like this

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    // code to only run at first page load here 
}
```

Otherwise you will initiate the label.Text to an empty string on each postback of the page and the page will be (more or less) static.

Comment: Custon event in control : `EventHandler SubmitHandler = (EventHandler)Events[EventSubmitKey];                SubmitHandler(this, e);`